# Inject space (if missing) after all commas, except thousand separators

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to build a macro to find commas(,) in a text and if there is not a space after it, i.e. before the next word in the text, then add a space.

My problem is I have to write numeric values in Arabic and so I usually use commas as thousand separator (1,000); therefore I need a code to neglect numeric values while searching for commas with the specified feature.

---

I already have the following code (the important part of it):

```
With Selection.Find 
 .Text = "،"
 .Replacement.Text = "، "
End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

but this code does not distinguish between words and numbers

Comment: You want to transform `sure,but -> sure, but` and `1,000` should stay?

Comment: Ok...I'm not experienced with Macros, but my approach would be using regular expressions. I'm pretty sure, VBA supports them in some way. Problem is this: `My farotie numbers are 10,200 and 567.` with a missing space before '200'. It's difficult to tell if this a number or a sequence of numbers. What have you tried so far?

Comment: thanks, the explanation added above beneath the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already wrote in my comment, regular expressions are what you need. I just did a little google search and found [this Tutorial](http://www.macrostash.com/2011/10/08/simple-regular-expression-tutorial-for-excel-vba/). There you should get enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, I'll work on it. in fact I didn't know what "regular expressions" are. after all I am a beginner user of macros.

Comment: You're welcome. Regular expressions isn't really a beginners topic, but on the other hand it's not this hard to understand. Hope you'll have fun learning ;) @SaeedMehrdad